# How to Add Tab to dotProject's Project page?

Tags: php, dotproject

I'm a newbie in PHP. A friend of mine want me to help him set up a Project Management intranet with dotProject. The first request I receive from my friend is add a new tab on Projects page. Does anyone can give me clue on how to do it, since lack of documentation on dotProject website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Former dotProject contributor here.. if you want to add a new project status, go to your System Admin -> System Lookup Values -> and find ProjectStatus in that list. Edit that row and add the status you're looking for. Be careful about changing the order.

Also, as an alternative.. a couple years back, a few of us from dotProject forked the system into a new application called web2project - http://web2project.net/  We've closed 100+ issues and added 40+ features and are coming up on our v2.0 release this month. There is an upgrade path from dotProject too.